# How to write a function to read ARM CPSR in either ARM or THUMB mode?

Tags: gcc, arm

I am working on an ARMv7 (Cortex-A7) system, and I want to read CPSR from C file in either ARM mode or THUMB mode.

Firstly, I used the embedded ASSEMBLY instruction in C function as follows,

```
 __asm__ volatile("mrs %0, CPSR\n" : "=r"(regval));
```

When I compiled the C file with -mthumb and ran the code with GDB, it showed that the regval is 0x60000010 which is NOT the 0x60000030 shown by GDB!

So how to write a function to read CPSR in either ARM or THUMB mode?

#### Updated with compiling option

a) Build the code with following command line to specify the THUMB mode.
`arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -g2 backtrace.c -mcpu=cortex-a7 -static -mthumb -o tbacktrace`
Run tbacktrace with qemu and GDB, I got different value as,

```
(gdb) p/x regval
$7 = 0x60000010
(gdb) p/x $cpsr
$8 = 0x60000030
```

The question is why my `mrs %0, CPSR\n` showd CPSR is ARM mode, instead of THUMB mode which the code is built.

b) When build the code with command line (not specify -mcpu=cortex-a7),

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -g2 backtrace.c -mthumb -o tbacktrace
```

there reported the following error.

```
$ arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -g2 backtrace.c -mthumb -o tbacktrace
/tmp/ccOg2tlo.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccOg2tlo.s:2256: Error: selected processor does not support `mrs r3,CPSR' in Thumb mode
/tmp/ccOg2tlo.s:2398: Error: selected processor does not support `mrs r3,CPSR' in Thumb mode
```

c) Build the code without -mcpu or -mthumb, the code can be built and ran well.
So I think there should be some other ways to get *right* CPSR in both ARM and THUMB modes.

##### Updated with more assembly codes.

arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -M force-thumb -d a.elf shows following,

```
4000014c:       0ff0            lsrs    r0, r6, #31
4000014e:       e92d 0f30       stmdb   sp!, {r4, r5, r8, r9, sl, fp}
40000152:       ee30 3407       cdp     4, 3, cr3, cr0, cr7, {0}
40000156:       e210            b.n     4000057a <__aeabi_f2d+0x16>
40000158:       3ba3            subs    r3, #163        ; 0xa3
4000015a:       e1a0            b.n     4000049e <__adddf3+0x1f6>
4000015c:       001b            movs    r3, r3
4000015e:       0a00            lsrs    r0, r0, #8
40000160:       a000            add     r0, pc, #0      ; (adr r0, 40000164 <B_Loop1>)
40000162:       e3a0            b.n     400008a6 <__udivmoddi4+0x19a>

......
400002a8 <__adddf3>:
400002a8:       b530            push    {r4, r5, lr}
400002aa:       ea4f 0441       mov.w   r4, r1, lsl #1
400002ae:       ea4f 0543       mov.w   r5, r3, lsl #1
400002b2:       ea94 0f05       teq     r4, r5
400002b6:       bf08            it      eq
400002b8:       ea90 0f02       teqeq   r0, r2
400002bc:       bf1f            itttt   ne
```

Here is a part of code of the project, which is built with -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-a7.
As Nate and Frant mentioned, I think the code is running in THUMB mode, and checking Tbit of CPSR to detect ARM or THUMB mode is un-necessary, is it correct?

##### A way to detect THUMB or ARM mode

After reading Nate's and Frant's comments, I had an idea to detect which mode the CPU is not by reading Tbit of CPSR.  The idea is by reading PC register two times, and check the difference. If it is 2 (length of THUMB instruction), CPU is running in THUMB mode, if it is 4 (length of ARM instruction), CPU is in ARM mode.
The code is as follows,

```
register uint32_t pc1, pc2;
asm volatile("mov %0, pc\n mov %1, pc" : "=r"(pc1), "=r"(pc2));
```

I built the code with and without -mthumb, with -Os, the code seems to be able to detect the THUMB or ARM mode.

Comment: `asm volatile("mrs %0, CPSR" : "=&r"(regval));` should be fine. If that does not work, something else is not done properly.

Comment: The instruction does NOT work as expected! So the question is 'what else' is NOT done properly?

Comment: Your question does now contain some critical information that was missing.  What is still not clear to me is why you think the instruction is not working, and what exactly is the value for `CPSR` you would expect. The fact that  `p/x regval` and `p/x $cpsr` are not returning the same value in a `GDB` session is a quite different topic I.M.H.O.

Comment: Let me clarify what is my expectation. I compiled the code with `-mthumb` option, the code SHOULD be running in THUMB mode, the CPSR read out to `regval` should have Tbit (bit 5) set, that is 0x60000030, the 0x60000010 is NOT the THUMB mode I expected. Here is the assembly code shown in GDB (I think it is working in THUMB mode). 
`0x00011226 <+0>:     push    {r7, lr}`
`0x00011228 <+2>:     sub     sp, #8`
`0x0001122a <+4>:     add     r7, sp, #0`
`0x0001122c <+6>:     movw    r0, #37008      ; 0x9090`
`

Comment: I am not sure about that:  the code compiled with `-mthumb ` is really executing in Thumb mode - See the information  that was added to the answer, and [Nate Eldredge's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge) answer explains why the `T` bit is being dropped when executing `MRS` in Thumb mode, but is present in the `CPSR_USR` system register read by the JTAG probe.

Comment: I am using QEMU and GDB to test the codes (including your CPSR demo), and I could NOT find CPSR_USR in GDB register list, I'm still trying to find the way to detect the ARM or thumb mode.....

Comment: `CPSR_USR` is the name used by ozone for the value of the CPSR register when the CPU is in user mode. I added an example using a JLink JTAG probe and GDB 12.1, and `cpsr` is the right register name to use when using GDB for reading the value of `CPSR` in user mode. Other names used by GDB would be `cpsr_fiq`, `cpsr_irq`, `cpsr_abt` and `cpsr_und`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CPSR.c`:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  uint32_t regval;
  asm volatile("mrs %0, CPSR" : "=r"(regval));
  return regval;
}
```

If you don't use `-mcpu=cortex-a7`, your compiler will default to another CPU:

```text
/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -O0 -nostartfiles -nostdlib -Wl,--section-start=.text=0x80800000 -S CPSR.c

cat CPSR.s 
        .cpu arm7tdmi
        .arch armv4t
```

The ARM7TDMI-S  was introduced in 2001, and, as pointed out by your compiler, does not seem to support `mrs r3,CPSR` in Thumb mode. Therefore, you must specify `-mcpu=cortex-a7`:

```text
/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a7 -O0 -nostartfiles -nostdlib -Wl,--section-start=.text=0x80800000 -S CPSR.c

cat CPSR.s 
       .cpu cortex-a7
       .arch armv7-a
```

CPU and architecture are now as expected.

Testing your code on real hardware - a Cortex-A7 running `u-boot` - in Arm and Thumb mode:

Arm:

```text
/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -O0 -mcpu=cortex-a7 -marm -nostartfiles -nostdlib -Wl,--section-start=.text=0x80800000 -o CPSR-arm.elf CPSR.c
/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000080800000
/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O srec CPSR-arm.elf CPSR-arm.srec
/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump -j .text -D CPSR-arm.elf

CPSR-arm.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

80800000 <main>:
80800000:       e52db004        push    {fp}            ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
80800004:       e28db000        add     fp, sp, #0
80800008:       e24dd01c        sub     sp, sp, #28
8080000c:       e50b0010        str     r0, [fp, #-16]
80800010:       e50b1014        str     r1, [fp, #-20]  ; 0xffffffec
80800014:       e50b2018        str     r2, [fp, #-24]  ; 0xffffffe8
80800018:       e10f3000        mrs     r3, CPSR
8080001c:       e50b3008        str     r3, [fp, #-8]
80800020:       e51b3008        ldr     r3, [fp, #-8]
80800024:       e1a00003        mov     r0, r3
80800028:       e28bd000        add     sp, fp, #0
8080002c:       e49db004        pop     {fp}            ; (ldr fp, [sp], #4)
80800030:       e12fff1e        bx      lr
```

I.MX7d running u-boot:

```text
# loads
## Ready for S-Record download ...

## First Load Addr = 0x80800000
## Last  Load Addr = 0x80800033
## Total Size      = 0x00000034 = 52 Bytes
CACHE: Misaligned operation at range [80800000, 80800034]
## Start Addr      = 0x80800000
# go 0x80800000
## Starting application at 0x80800000 ...
## Application terminated, rc = 0x200000D3
```

Thumb:

```text
/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -O0 -mcpu=cortex-a7 -mthumb -nostartfiles -nostdlib -Wl,--section-start=.text=0x80800000 -o CPSR-thumb.elf CPSR.c
/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/10.3.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld: warning: cannot find entry symbol _start; defaulting to 0000000080800000
/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O srec CPSR-thumb.elf CPSR-thumb.srec
/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-none-eabi-10.3-2021.10/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump -j .text -D CPSR-thumb.elf

CPSR-thumb.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

80800000 <main>:
80800000:       b480            push    {r7}
80800002:       b087            sub     sp, #28
80800004:       af00            add     r7, sp, #0
80800006:       60f8            str     r0, [r7, #12]
80800008:       60b9            str     r1, [r7, #8]
8080000a:       607a            str     r2, [r7, #4]
8080000c:       f3ef 8300       mrs     r3, CPSR
80800010:       617b            str     r3, [r7, #20]
80800012:       697b            ldr     r3, [r7, #20]
80800014:       4618            mov     r0, r3
80800016:       371c            adds    r7, #28
80800018:       46bd            mov     sp, r7
8080001a:       bc80            pop     {r7}
8080001c:       4770            bx      lr
```

I.MX7d running u-boot:

```text
# loads
## Ready for S-Record download ...

## First Load Addr = 0x80800000
## Last  Load Addr = 0x8080001D
## Total Size      = 0x0000001E = 30 Bytes
CACHE: Misaligned operation at range [80800000, 8080001e]
## Start Addr      = 0x80800000
# 
# go 0x80800001
## Starting application at 0x80800001 ...
## Application terminated, rc = 0x200000D3
```

Bottom-line, both versions returned the same value for CPSR, i.e. `0x200000D3`.

To the question

> How to write a function to read ARM CPSR in either ARM or THUMB mode?

The answer would then be: The way you did.
Asking why `p/x regval` and `p/x $cpsr` are not returning the same value should be the topic for a different question, may be on the GDB forum.

---

Update #1: [Nate Eldredge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oqadw.png) explained why the value read into the register has always the `T` bit set to zero.

Testing on a different `Cortex-A7` (Allwinner H3), a JLink probe and the Ozone debugger, we can see that even though the value read by the `MRS` instruction is `0x200000D3`, the value of `CPSR_USR` read by the JTAG probe and Ozone is  `0x200001F3` when executing the Thumb version, and `0x200000D3` when executing the Arm version:

Arm:

[image: Arm - disassembly]

[image: Arm - general purpose/system registers]

Thumb:

[image: Thumb - disassembly]

[image: Thumb - general purpose/system registers]

This would I.M.H.O. perfectly validate his explanation.

---

Update #2

Still using the JLink debug probe, but in combination with `JLinkGDBServerExe` and `arm-none-eabi-gdb` 12.1 in TUI mode:

Arm:

[image: GDB debug window - Arm mode]

[image: R3/CPSR values - Arm mode]

Thumb:

[image: GDB debug window - Thumb mode]

[image: R3/CPSR values - Thumb mode]

The value for the `CPSR` register read by the JTAG probe is the one you would expect, i.e. has the `T`bit set in Thumb mode.

You probably would get the same result in Linux using a TRACE32 JTAG probe.

Not sure this could be useful, but note that some pre-defined symbols differ when building an Arm or Thumb executable:

```text
/opt/arm/11/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -dM -E -mcpu=cortex-a7 -marm - < /dev/null | grep -i arm
#define __ARM_SIZEOF_WCHAR_T 4
#define __ARM_FEATURE_SAT 1
#define __ARM_ARCH_ISA_ARM 1
#define __ARMEL__ 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_IDIV 1
#define __ARM_SIZEOF_MINIMAL_ENUM 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_LDREX 15
#define __ARM_PCS 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_QBIT 1
#define __ARM_ARCH_PROFILE 65
#define __ARM_32BIT_STATE 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_CLZ 1
#define __ARM_ARCH_ISA_THUMB 2
#define __ARM_ARCH 7
#define __ARM_FEATURE_UNALIGNED 1
#define __arm__ 1
#define __ARM_ARCH_7A__ 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_SIMD32 1
#define __ARM_FEATURE_COPROC 15
#define __ARM_FEATURE_DSP 1
#define __ARM_ARCH_EXT_IDIV__ 1
#define __ARM_EABI__ 1

/opt/arm/11/arm-gnu-toolchain-11.3.rel1-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -dM -E -mcpu=cortex-a7 -mthumb - < /dev/null | grep -i thumb
#define __thumb2__ 1
#define __THUMB_INTERWORK__ 1
#define __thumb__ 1
#define __ARM_ARCH_ISA_THUMB 2
#define __THUMBEL__ 1
```

You could therefore use `#ifdef __arm__`  and `#ifdef __thumb2__` statements in your code in order to know if you are executing the Arm or the Thumb version.

Comment: I updated the question with more details. My puzzlement is why the code is built with `-mthumb` returned the CPSR as 0x60000010 (ARM mode) not 0x60000030 (Tbit is 1).

Comment: [Nate Eldredge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/634919/nate-eldredge) answered this question and the original one. I think I did answer your original question too, in a different way though:  your code  is working fine on a Cortex-A7 (and correctly returning the same value in both Arm and thumb modes).

Comment: Thank you so much for your code and detailed demo, it is really helpful.

Comment: Frant, thanks for your update#2. It also confirmed that JTAG probe can do what I want. Is there a reliable way in the runtime to get the mode? Or as Nate mentioned the thumb codes run in thumb mode naturally, no need to further check the mode?

Comment: The purpose of using the JTAG probe was just to confirm GDB was displaying the correct values in your case: this is normal that you are reading  `0x60000010` in regval and that GDB is displaying `0x60000030` as the value for the `CPSR` register. You therefore don't need anything more than you already have. And you can get the mode using the predefined symbols, since, as explained in a comment hereafter, your code, once compiled, will either run in Arm mode or in Thumb mode - not both at the same time.

Comment: yep, it seemed that the code in my project has something wrong in detecting CPU mode by directly reading Tbit of CPSR in runtime. And I may remove the code and take it for granted that CPU is running THUMB mode, since the code is built with -mthumb.

Comment: This should suffice, yes, and if you want to be sure, you can test for the definition of the `__arm__`  or `__thumb__`/`__thumb2__`,  predefined symbols, since their values will always  match the `-marm` or `-mthumb` option you will use at compile-time. Note that  `__thumb2_`  would obviously  not be defined when compiling for an older architecture not supporting the Thumb2 instruction set.

Comment: I added following codes to check which symbol is defined, like this
`#ifdef __arm__
#warning "Built for ARM mode"
#endif
`
`#ifdef __thumb__
#warning "Built for THUMB mode"
#endif`
When I built it as `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -mcpu=cortex-a7 -mthumb cpsr.c`, to my surprise, both warning messages are shown.

Comment: You are right. You should rather test whether or not the `__thumb__`  symbol is defined, since it would only be defined in the case the code would be compiled with the `-mthumb` option. I just checked.

Comment: Got you and thans for your confirmation.

Comment: I posted another question on how to download binary file to ARM board with JLINK (v6.72), https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75273225/how-to-load-binary-to-dram-with-jlink-jtag-to-debug, could you help checking this question? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The instruction is working as designed and documented.

The discrepancy is in bit 5, which according to the [ARMv7-A Architecture Reference Manual](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0406/b/System-Level-Architecture/The-System-Level-Programmers--Model/ARM-processor-modes-and-core-registers/Program-Status-Registers--PSRs-), is the T bit, indicating whether the processor is in Thumb state.  It's one of the "execution state bits".  Lower down on that page, under "Accessing the execution state bits", it says:

> The execution state bits, other than the E bit, are RAZ [read as zero] when read by an MRS instruction.

So `mrs rN, CPSR` masks off those bits.  I'm not sure why it's designed this way.  But in principle you should already know whether you're in Thumb state or not, so it shouldn't really be necessary to read this information from CPSR.

On the other hand, gdb doesn't get its CPSR value from `mrs rN, CPSR`.  I haven't checked, but I presume what happens is this: when your program hits a breakpoint, an exception is generated.  This causes CPSR to be saved into SPSR (without masking any bits!), and the kernel's exception handler retrieves it from there to store as part of the saved context of your process, along with register values, etc.  The saved context is made available to the debugger via appropriate system calls (e.g. `ptrace(2)`) and that's how it is able to display register contents and such.  In particular, it gets the CPSR value that was saved at the breakpoint and which isn't masked.

Comment: Thank you for the disclosure of GDB internal, and I got your point. I need to find a concrete way to get CPU's mode instead of reading the Tbit of CPSR.

Comment: @wangt13: What is the point of that?  If you're executing Thumb instructions then you must be in Thumb state, or your program would have already crashed.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. The project I am working on might be mixed in ARM or THUMB modes, a function is called in either ARM mode or THUMB mode, that is why I need a way to know what is current CPU mode.

Comment: I don't think that's possible.  Whatever binary instructions your function contains, they will be valid in either ARM state or Thumb state, not both.  So if you try to execute the same function in both modes, one of them will crash.  I mean, even the very instruction in question: `mrs r3, CSPR` - what bytes do you actually want in your program?  `0xe10f3000` will only work in ARM mode, and `f3ef 8300` will only work in Thumb mode.

Comment: @wangt13: Normally you would just compile your function for one of the states, and use `blx` when calling it so that the state is switched if required.  Is there a reason you can't do that?  This is sounding a lot like an XY problem, so maybe you should give more context and explain why you believe you need to test the state, or to have code that can run in either state.  What larger problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @wangt13: I mean, I guess there is such a thing as "polyglot" code that would execute in both modes as different (valid) instructions, and could be used to selectively branch to ARM or Thumb code as needed.  But it's hard to see why you would use that, outside of things like exploit code.

Comment: I put more codes in the question, it is from the ELF of a library in the project. Can I conclude when CPU runs the code it is in THUMB mode?

Comment: @wangt13: The only way to be 100.00000% certain is to check every place in the program that might call this code.  But it certainly looks like it's *intended* to be run in Thumb state, since the disassembly into Thumb instructions looks like sensible code.  You could try disassembling the same code as ARM instructions and I bet it will be nonsense.  If the program seems to have been created by a person or compiler who knew what they were doing, then I would assume it actually *is* always called in Thumb state, unless you have some specific reason to think that it's not.

Comment: I did the objdump -d cpsr.elf without `-M force-thumb` (I did not found how to do force-arm disassembling) and found the application codes are still THUMB instructions. And the libc functions like `_start`, `__libc_start_main` are all ARM instructions (I compiled cpsr.c with `-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-a7 -static`), so I think libc calls main with `blx` to switch mode to THUMB.