# How to load binary to DRAM with JLink JTAG to debug?

Tags: arm, jtag

I am doing a ARM+RTOS project, and I want to download the binary to target board with JLink JTAG.
But every time 'loadbin a.bin 0x40000000' will report error -1, and says 'failed to read memory', 0x40000000 is the starting address of DRAM.

I have to use 'r' command to reset JTAG port to read memory back.
The JLINK driver is 6.72 installed in Ubuntu-20.04.5, the ARM is an allwinner chip (cortex-a7).

I am wondering how to download the binary image into DRAM thru JLink JTAG to debug.

##### Updated with more details.

The board is based on sun8i, with 2 ARMv7 cores.
The JLink can identify the JTAG adapter as follows,

```
Connecting to target via JTAG
ConfigTargetSettings() start
Setting up: AW Cortex-A7
ConfigTargetSettings() end
TotalIRLen = 4, IRPrint = 0x01
JTAG chain detection found 1 devices:
 #0 Id: 0x5BA00477, IRLen: 04, CoreSight JTAG-DP
AP map detection skipped. Manually configured AP map found.
AP[0]: AHB-AP (IDR: Not set)
AP[1]: APB-AP (IDR: Not set)
Using preconfigured AP[1] as APB-AP
AP[1]: APB-AP found
ROMTbl[0][0]: CompAddr: 80050000 CID: B105900D, PID:04-004BB906 CTI
ROMTbl[0][1]: CompAddr: 81000000 CID: B105100D, PID:08-00A9CC32 ROM Table
ROMTbl[1][0]: CompAddr: 81010000 CID: 00000000, PID:00-00000000 ???
ROMTbl[1][1]: CompAddr: 81020000 CID: 00000000, PID:00-00000000 ???
ROMTbl[1][2]: CompAddr: 81400000 CID: B105100D, PID:04-000BB4A7 ROM Table
ROMTbl[2][0]: CompAddr: 81410000 CID: B105900D, PID:04-005BBC07 Cortex-A7
Found Cortex-A7 r0p5
6 code breakpoints, 4 data breakpoints
Debug architecture ARMv7.1
Data endian: little
Main ID register: 0x410FC075
I-Cache L1: 32 KB, 512 Sets, 32 Bytes/Line, 2-Way
D-Cache L1: 32 KB, 128 Sets, 64 Bytes/Line, 4-Way
Unified-Cache L2: 256 KB, 512 Sets, 64 Bytes/Line, 8-Way
System control register:
  Instruction endian: little
  Level-1 instruction cache enabled
  Level-1 data cache enabled
  MMU enabled
  Branch prediction enabled
Memory zones:
  [0]: Default (Default access mode)
  [1]: AHB-AP (AP0) (DMA like acc. in AP0 addr. space)
  [2]: APB-AP (AP1) (DMA like acc. in AP1 addr. space)
Cortex-A7 identified.
```

The JLinkGDBServer and gdb can attach and debug the code running (burned with a tool in Windows) in RAM, such as reading memory, modify memory etc.

But the gdb command of `load a.elf` will fail with error in memory writing.

And the `loadbin a.bin 0x40000000` in JLinkExe also failed with memory writing.

##### with steps of loading add.c from Frant in my system

The JLinkGDBServer is running in another xterm, and run gdb-multiarch

```
(gdb) monitor reset
Resetting target
(gdb) x/8x 0x40000000
0x40000000:     0xea00001e      0x736f7472      0x00000000      0xa143480d
0x40000010:     0x0008b630      0x0008b630      0x0008b630      0x2e302e30

(gdb) load add.elf
`/home/t/develop/ctest/add.elf' has changed; re-reading symbols.
(no debugging symbols found)
Loading section .note.gnu.build-id, size 0x24 lma 0x100b4
Loading section .text, size 0x64 lma 0x40000000
Start address 0x40000000, load size 136
Transfer rate: 5 KB/sec, 68 bytes/write.

(gdb) x/8x 0x40000000
0x40000000 <main>:      Cannot access memory at address 0x40000000
```

Before loading elf to DRAM, memory at 0x40000000 (start of DRAM) can be read from GDB. But after loading elf, that memory cannot be read from GDB.

The JLinkGDBServer also reported...

```
Downloading 36 bytes @ address 0x000100B4
Downloading 100 bytes @ address 0x40000000
Writing register (PC = 0x40000000)
Reading all registers
WARNING: Failed to read memory @ address 0x40000000
```

Then, I changed to use JLinkExe to load a binary file of 4KB (all 0s) as follows,

```
J-Link>r
Reset delay: 0 ms
Reset type NORMAL: Toggle reset pin and halt CPU core.
J-Link>mem32 0x40000000 16
40000000 = EA00001E 736F7472 00000000 A143480D
40000010 = 0008B630 0008B630 0008B630 2E302E30
40000020 = 00000030 2E302E30 00000030 40000000
40000030 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
40000040 = 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
40000050 = 00000040 00000000
J-Link>loadbin zero.bin 0x40000000
Downloading file [zero.bin]...
Unspecified error -1
J-Link>
```

### Tried with sunxi-fel tool

```
(base):~/tools/sunxi-tools-master$ sudo ./sunxi-fel -v --list
USB device 001:035   Allwinner R528    93406400:0c004814:0146880a:044713cd

(base):~/tools/sunxi-tools-master$ sudo ./sunxi-fel -p write 0x40000000 ~/u-boot.bin
usb_bulk_send() ERROR -7: Operation timed out

(base):~/tools/sunxi-tools-master$ sudo ./sunxi-fel -v --list
usb_bulk_send() ERROR -7: Operation timed out
```

Firstly, sunxi-fel can detect and list the attached device.
Then to load u-boot.bin to DRAM hit an error (Maybe from DRAM not initialized).
Last, the sunxi-fel cannot detect and list the attached device, I have to power cycle the board to bring it back.

Comment: This is as I would expect it, as explained below, you cannot use the SDRAM without having executed the SPL spécific to your board using `sunxi-fel spl u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin`

Comment: The SOC vendor does NOT provide the u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin for me to download. I am not sure if I can build out a working version of u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin for their source codes.... I need to study the SUNXI's U-Boot codes.

Comment: If you have the source code, you should be able to build it. Would you have the link to the source code  for their u-boot ?

Comment: The source code of U-Boot is ported by the SoC vendor based on U-Boot 2018. The vendor releases it to my team with NDA, so it is NOT general available.

Comment: Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer, but in this case, I would say that, if they are not using 'jump tables', they are probably in breach of the [u-boot license](https://github.com/ARM-software/u-boot/blob/master/Licenses/README) . This would be strange, but not a first, to see infringers trying to cover their trail using an NDA, but if this were the case, they probably should be the ones  answering your questions - my two cents.

Comment: According to the guys at [linux-sunxi](https://linux-sunxi.org/Main_Page): "Allwinner is violating the GPLv2 license in several ways and has so far not shown willingness to resolve this."

Comment: I am not a lawyer either, what I can do is to make the project using AW SOC work. The legal team/guys should deal with it.

Comment: I hear you, I know that feeling...

Comment: @Frant I posted another question on accessing ROMTable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75442910/how-to-access-arm-coresight-romtable-from-software, could you help checking that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not clear from your original question what the state of your device is prior to your attempt, nor what exact model of SBC you are using.

However, here are two different approaches you could probably use for achieving your goal. Ubuntu 22.04, Jlink software V7.84c, a JLink EDU and a FriendlyElec nanopi-2 neo with an Allwinner H3 were used for the purpose of this answer.

They could probably be adapted to a different 32 bit Alwinner SoC having JTAG support, and an SBC having the JTAG signals properly wired.

It worked for me using a nanopi2-m1 and an orangepi-zero.

You have two issues to solve here prior to be able to upload your binary usin g the JLink probe:

- Making sure the SDRAM controller is configured so that the SDRAM will be readable/writable,
- Enable the JTAG on some PIO port supporting the JTAG functionality: for example, the reset value for the H3 PA Configure Register is 0x77777777, that is the JAG functionality is not enable at reset. As a side-effect, if you are resetting the SoC using the JLink probe, you will lose the JTAG connectivity.

**Approach #1 - using u-boot**

In this case, the u-boot SPL will obviously already have configured the SDRAM controller, and its content will be usable, and you will just have to enable the JTAG functionality on PIO port A.

You will need to write the value `0x77223333` into the  PA Configure Register at address `0x01c20800` in order to enable the JTAG functionality on PIO port A- please refer to `4.22.1. Port Controller Register List` and `4.22.2. Port Controller Register Description` of the [Allwinner H3 Datasheet](https://dl.linux-sunxi.org/H3/Allwinner_H3_Datasheet_V1.0.pdf).

```text
U-Boot SPL 2023.01 (Jan 24 2023 - 15:18:15 -0500)
DRAM: 512 MiB
Trying to boot from MMC1


U-Boot 2023.01 (Jan 24 2023 - 15:18:15 -0500) Allwinner Technology

CPU:   Allwinner H3 (SUN8I 1680)
Model: FriendlyARM NanoPi NEO
DRAM:  512 MiB
Core:  60 devices, 17 uclasses, devicetree: separate
WDT:   Not starting watchdog@1c20ca0
MMC:   mmc@1c0f000: 0
Loading Environment from FAT... OK
In:    serial
Out:   serial
Err:   serial
Net:   eth0: ethernet@1c30000
starting USB...
Bus usb@1c1a000: probe failed, error -2
Bus usb@1c1a400: probe failed, error -2
Bus usb@1c1d000: USB EHCI 1.00
Bus usb@1c1d400: USB OHCI 1.0
scanning bus usb@1c1d000 for devices... 1 USB Device(s) found
scanning bus usb@1c1d400 for devices... 1 USB Device(s) found
       scanning usb for storage devices... 0 Storage Device(s) found
=>
```

Enabling JTAG on PA:

```text
 mw.l 0x01c20800 0x77223333 1
 =>
```

Starting the JLink GDD server - Ubuntu system:

```text
<!-- language-all: lang-text -->

/opt/jlink$/opt/JLink_Linux_V784c_x86_64/JLinkGDBServerCLExe -select USB -device Cortex-A7 -endian little -if JTAG -speed 4000 -noir -noLocalhostOnly -nologtofile -port 2331 -SWOPort 2332 -TelnetPort 2333
SEGGER J-Link GDB Server V7.84c Command Line Version

JLinkARM.dll V7.84c (DLL compiled Jan 20 2023 12:25:58)

Command line: -select USB -device Cortex-A7 -endian little -if JTAG -speed 4000 -noir -noLocalhostOnly -nologtofile -port 2331 -SWOPort 2332 -TelnetPort 2333
-----GDB Server start settings-----
GDBInit file:                  none
GDB Server Listening port:     2331
SWO raw output listening port: 2332
Terminal I/O port:             2333
Accept remote connection:      yes
Generate logfile:              off
Verify download:               off
Init regs on start:            off
Silent mode:                   off
Single run mode:               off
Target connection timeout:     0 ms
------J-Link related settings------
J-Link Host interface:         USB
J-Link script:                 none
J-Link settings file:          none
------Target related settings------
Target device:                 Cortex-A7
Target device parameters:      none
Target interface:              JTAG
Target interface speed:        4000kHz
Target endian:                 little

Connecting to J-Link...
J-Link is connected.
Firmware: J-Link ARM V8 compiled Nov 28 2014 13:44:46
Hardware: V8.00
S/N: ********
OEM: SEGGER-EDU
Feature(s): FlashBP, GDB
Checking target voltage...
Target voltage: 3.31 V
Listening on TCP/IP port 2331
Connecting to target...

J-Link found 1 JTAG device, Total IRLen = 4
JTAG ID: 0x5BA00477 (Cortex-A7)
Connected to target
Waiting for GDB connection...
```

At this stage, the JLink GDB server successfully connected the H3 using the JTAG interface.

We now need a small example program - `add.c`

```C
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    const int count = 5;
    int result = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
        result = result + i;
    }

done:
        // We should rather use 'WFI' here.
        goto done;
}
```

Compiling `add.elf`:

```text
/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-gcc -O0 -nostdlib -nostartfiles -e main -Wl,-Ttext=0x0000000042000000 -o add.elf add.c
/opt/arm/10/gcc-arm-10.3-2021.07-x86_64-arm-none-eabi/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump -D -j .text add.elf > add.lst
```

```
cat add.lst

add.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm

Disassembly of section .text:

42000000 <main>:
42000000:       e52db004        push    {fp}            ; (str fp, [sp, #-4]!)
42000004:       e28db000        add     fp, sp, #0
42000008:       e24dd01c        sub     sp, sp, #28
4200000c:       e50b0018        str     r0, [fp, #-24]  ; 0xffffffe8
42000010:       e50b101c        str     r1, [fp, #-28]  ; 0xffffffe4
42000014:       e3a03005        mov     r3, #5
42000018:       e50b3010        str     r3, [fp, #-16]
4200001c:       e3a03000        mov     r3, #0
42000020:       e50b3008        str     r3, [fp, #-8]
42000024:       e3a03001        mov     r3, #1
42000028:       e50b300c        str     r3, [fp, #-12]
4200002c:       ea000006        b       4200004c <main+0x4c>
42000030:       e51b2008        ldr     r2, [fp, #-8]
42000034:       e51b300c        ldr     r3, [fp, #-12]
42000038:       e0823003        add     r3, r2, r3
4200003c:       e50b3008        str     r3, [fp, #-8]
42000040:       e51b300c        ldr     r3, [fp, #-12]
42000044:       e2833001        add     r3, r3, #1
42000048:       e50b300c        str     r3, [fp, #-12]
4200004c:       e51b200c        ldr     r2, [fp, #-12]
42000050:       e51b3010        ldr     r3, [fp, #-16]
42000054:       e1520003        cmp     r2, r3
42000058:       bafffff4        blt     42000030 <main+0x30>
4200005c:       e1a00000        nop                     ; (mov r0, r0)
42000060:       eafffffe        b       42000060 <main+0x60>
```

Starting a GDB session and loading add.elf:

```
/opt/gdb/gdb-12.1-arm-none-eabi-x86_64-linux-gnu/bin/arm-none-eabi-gdb 
GNU gdb (GDB) 12.1
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=arm-none-eabi".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
(gdb) target remote localhost:2331
Remote debugging using localhost:2331
warning: No executable has been specified and target does not support
determining executable automatically.  Try using the "file" command.
0x42000004 in ?? ()
(gdb) load add.elf
Loading section .text, size 0x64 lma 0x42000000
Start address 0x42000000, load size 100
Transfer rate: 32 KB/sec, 100 bytes/write.
(gdb) b *0x42000000
Breakpoint 1 at 0x42000000
```

At this stage, the program was load into the nanipo2-neo,and a break-point
was set at `0x42000000`.

By switching to the `TUI` mode, we can step trough the program using the `stepi` command:

[image: Debugging add.elf GDB/JLink session in TUI mode]

**Approach #2 - using `FEL mode` and `sunxi-fel`**

With this approach, you would boot your SBC in `FEL` mode, configure the SDRAM controller using the following command: `sunxi-fel spl u-boot-sunxi-with-spl.bin`, as explained on the [FEL/USBBoot](https://linux-sunxi.org/FEL/USBBoot) page of the [linux-sunxi](https://linux-sunxi) WEB site.

Enabling the JTAG functionality could than be done using the following command: `sunxi-fel writel 0x01c20800 0x77223333`.

Starting the JLink GDB server and launching a GDB debug session could then be done as described above.

Comment: Hi Frant, sorry for lacking of details which was updated today. I am not familar with JLink toolset, my latest experience with JTAG in embedded system is about 20+years ago, when the JTAG can full control the SOC. With this capability, I can do baremetal debugging. I am not sure if JLink support a startup script to do memory controller initialization so that I can train the DRAM then load the image to RAM to debug and run. I have not tried FEL mode, because Allwinner packed the uboot+RTOS to a data file to flash to the nand. I don't know how to play with sunxi-fel with u-boot. I am trying....

Comment: You would use u-boot or sunxi-fel and FEL mode, not both. On my H3/H2+, if I were doing a `monitor reset`, I would probably lose the JTAG connectivity because of the PIO port configuration register would be reset to its default, JTAG disabled, value. What SoC/SBC model are you using ? which PIO PINs is your JTAG setup connectet to ? This would allow checking in the datasheet if performing a reset is an issue or not. I was able to make the example above work without issuing any `monitor reset` command. You should probably give it a try.

Comment: The SOC is SUN8iw20 compatible，I checked its datasheet, it seemed JTAG is muxed with PF. The target board has booted up to RTOS, then I started JLinkExe/JLinkGDBServer to attach to target board and loaded image to DRAM (0x40000000), it failed with memory read/write. I also need to ask Allwinner for the comments. I don't know what happened when `load add.elf` or `loadbin add.bin 0x40000000`, which caused the JLink to report 'memory read/write error'.....

Comment: This will be difficult to help you further without having the answers to the questions I asked above: 1) What exact SoC/SBC model are you using ? 2) Which PIO PINs is your JTAG setup connected to ? 3) Did you try without performing a `monitor reset`? Thanks!

Comment: 1) SOC is AW R528 s2 (I am not sure it is released). 2) From the SOC datasheet, JTAG is muxed with PIO_F, I need to double check with board vendor. 3) I use monitor reset just after `load add.elf` and got the error of memory reading/writing. I don't use it at beginning. The board is booted up to RTOS tasks with uboot, so I think the DRAM is working, then I started `JLinkGDBServer` or `JLinkExe` to download a new binary image to DRAM to do debugging.

Comment: Could you stop in u-boot, execute the following command `printenv kernel_addr_r` and provide the output ? How much SDRAM does your SBC have ? And yes, it seems that four of the PIO_F pins can be used for JTAG purpose when configured in function mode 3, but they need to be somewhat configured in this mode.

Comment: After upgrading JLink to ver.7.0.0, it can work as expected. I can exploit the Image Debugging from within RAM. Thanks for your answer and comments.

Comment: This is good new. If you appreciate the help, and consider I provided a valid answer (example working  on an Allwinner Cortex-A7, JLink and Jlink software V7.84c)  , feel free to accept it. There is of course no obligation to do this.

Comment: Yep, I definitely accept your answer. BTW, I found the directories in V7.84D is different with 7.0.0, there is NO Devices/ or JLinkDevices.xml in /opt/SEGGER/Jlink. I wonder how to add the new SOC support to the new V7.84D. If you think it is better for me to post another SO question on it for your answering, please let me know.

Comment: If 7.0.0 is working fine, I would suggest just to keep using it for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

After upgraded to JLink ver.7.0.0，the image downloading and debugging in DRAM are working well as expected.