# How to access ARM coresight ROMTable from software?

Tags: debugging, arm

I am working on an ARMv7 system which has cortex-A7 cores.
With Jlink (via JTAG interface) I can see the ROMTable dumped when started JLinkExe as follows,

```
AP[1]: APB-AP found
ROMTbl[0][0]: CompAddr: 80050000 CID: B105900D, PID: 004BB906 CTI
ROMTbl[0][1]: CompAddr: 81000000 CID: B105100D, PID: 00A9CC32 ROM Table
ROMTbl[1][0]: CompAddr: 81010000 CID: 00000000, PID: 00000000 ???
ROMTbl[1][1]: CompAddr: 81020000 CID: 00000000, PID: 00000000 ???
ROMTbl[1][2]: CompAddr: 81400000 CID: B105100D, PID: 000BB4A7 ROM Table
ROMTbl[2][0]: CompAddr: 81410000 CID: B105900D, PID: 005BBC07 Cortex-A7
Found Cortex-A7 r0p5
```

By reading the ARMv7 spec, I found the base address of ROM Table can be read out from DBGDRAR. So I tried that in software. Then I also tried dumping the whole ROM Table from software by reading the physical address of ROM Table, but I got a data abort exception, seemed that the address is NOT accessible.

If it is not accessible, how can I read the ROMTable, or how does JLinkExe get the ROMTable?
Thanks,

Comment: IMO you cannot access from cpu, these address can only be accessed by DAP

Comment: Really? I did not find the ARM's document to define the access scope of DAP, is there any link to say that or give us the hints that it is NOT accessable from CPU?